# IP address to Int

Tags: node.js, go, ip

So I am having an issue with converting IPv4 and IPv6 to Int, I however have found this handy Go script which does it, however I need it for NodeJS.

I have tried the plugins in NPM including `ip2int` but it seems to be broken, and only work for IPv4.

I am wondering if anyone would know how to convert GO into Javascript for nodeJS. As I know the following code works in Go.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
    "net"
)

func Ip2Int(ip net.IP) *big.Int {
    i := big.NewInt(0)
    i.SetBytes(ip)
    return i
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(Ip2Int(net.ParseIP("20.36.77.12").To4()).String())
    fmt.Println(Ip2Int(net.ParseIP("2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334").To16()).String())
}
```

The reason why we need to parse the IP addresses to int is so that when we receive the IP address we can search to see if that IP address is inside one of the ranges of IP addresses that we have collected.

For example RAPD returns

```
 "startAddress": "35.192.0.0",
  "endAddress": "35.207.255.255",
```

so if we convert both of those to int we can store them in our DB and do a `gte` or `lte` search and see if the IP address is in between any of the stored values.

Comment: So, an IP address is not a single integer.  It's 4 separate integers (in IPv4) in sequence.  What's your purpose for trying to convert to a single number and what exact format are you wanting it to be as a single integer?  Do you just want to weight each of the 4 numbers by their 256 power?  Or what?  If you explain the actual end problem rather than just asking about a piece of some solution, we can probably help better.

Comment: @jfriend00 added it:
For example RAPD returns

 "startAddress": "35.192.0.0",
  "endAddress": "35.207.255.255",
so if we convert both of those to int we can store them in our DB and do a gte or lte search and see if the IP address is in between any of the stored values.

Comment: Is this your actual question: convert IP addresses to a representation that supports gte and lte in a database?

Comment: Well, your problem as stated is solved by func(ip any) int { return 0 }. Which hints at a unclear problem description.

Comment: @Volker the above code is for Go not NodeJS, they are two different systems, the go script works fine.

Comment: Do you realize that a purely numeric ipv6 address is 128 bits which doesn't fit in a Javascript double with full precision.

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Update: use BigInt's in case of ipv6 in response to comments below*

See [this solution](https://gist.github.com/jppommet/5708697?permalink_comment_id=4100281#gistcomment-4100281).

For IPv4 use:

```js
ipv4.split('.').reduce(function(int, value) { return int * 256 + +value })
```

For IPv6 you first need to parse the hex values and the hex values represent 2 bytes:

```js
ipv6.split(':').split(':').map(str => Number('0x'+str)).reduce(function(int, value) { return BigInt(int) * BigInt(65536) + BigInt(+value) })
```

I've also added the ipv6 solution to the referenced gist.

Comment: It looks to me like your ipv6 scheme runs out of precision in a Javascript double and thus `"2001:0db8:0:0:8d3:0:0:0"` and `"2001:0db8:0:0:8d3:0:0:1"` give you the same result.

Comment: The following worked well, But I will also back up @jfriend00 as when I ran a few tests, it also returned same values, however saying that because we need greater or equal it really is a small issue, as we check with the startAddress and endAddress and then the users IP address if it's greater or less then start and end than it's a match.

Comment: @RUSSELLHARROWER - You are losing significant digits so this is not swept under the rug by using gte.  The comparison is just not accurate on the least significant digits of an ipv6 address.  The comparison could be off either way depending upon which is the boundary value in the comparison and which is the test value.  The crux of the problem is that an IPv6 address is 128 bits which is more significant digits than can fit into a Javascript number.  Check your database to see if they have a numeric type that can be 128 bits and see how you would populate that into the database.

Comment: You are right @jfriend00. My answer not correct. I've updated to ipv6 conversion to use BigInts. Of course the database also needs to support these.

Comment: @Eelco I can't find BigInt in NodeJS - any suggestions?

Comment: @RUSSELLHARROWER NodeJS supports BigInt's from of version 10.4 so if you are using an older version you are out of luck I'm afraid.

Comment: If you cannot use BigInt I guess you could possibly split up the ipv6 address into 2 strings and use the initial ipv6 code fragment (without the BigInt conversions) to calculate 2 numbers, a most significant and a least significant number and use those in your comparisons.

Comment: I have Node -v 14.7.0 so should work @Eelco

Comment: In that case you should be fine. Some more information on working with BigInt and their limitations (in 2018) can be found here: https://thecodebarbarian.com/an-overview-of-bigint-in-node-js.html

Answer (score 1):

```
const IPv4ToInt = ipv4 => ipv4.split(".").reduce((a, b) => a << 8 | b) >>> 0;
```

and a simple IPv6 implementation:

```
const IPv6ToBigInt = ipv6 => BigInt("0x" + ipv6.toLowerCase().split(":").map(v => v.padStart(4, 0)).join(""));
```

or a more extensive one

```js
// normalizes several IPv6 formats to the long version
// in this format a string sort is equivalent to a numeric sort
const normalizeIPv6 = (ipv6) => {
  // for embedded IPv4 in IPv6.
  // like "::ffff:127.0.0.1"
  ipv6 = ipv6.replace(/\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/, ipv4 => {
    const [a, b, c, d] = ipv4.split(".");
    return (a << 8 | b).toString(16) + ":" + (c << 8 | d).toString(16)
  });

  // shortened IPs
  // like "2001:db8::1428:57ab"
  ipv6 = ipv6.replace("::", ":".repeat(10 - ipv6.split(":").length));

  return ipv6.toLowerCase().split(":").map(v => v.padStart(4, 0)).join(":");
}

const IPv6ToBigInt = ipv6 => BigInt("0x" + normalizeIPv6(ipv6).replaceAll(":", ""));

// tests
[
  "2001:0db8:85a3:08d3:1319:8a2e:0370:7344",
  "2001:0db8:85a3:08d3:1319:8a2e:0370:7345", // check precision
  "2001:db8:0:8d3:0:8a2e:70:7344",
  "2001:db8:0:0:0:0:1428:57ab",
  "2001:db8::1428:57ab",
  "2001:0db8:0:0:8d3:0:0:0",
  "2001:db8:0:0:8d3::",
  "2001:db8::8d3:0:0:0",
  "::ffff:127.0.0.1",
  "::ffff:7f00:1"
].forEach(ip => console.log({
  ip,
  normalized: normalizeIPv6(ip),
  bigInt: IPv6ToBigInt(ip).toString() // toString() or SO console doesn't print them.
}));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```